# The image of the canonical map into the double dual of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

If $V$ is a vector space over some field, we have a canonical map $\phi_V:V\to V^{**}$ from $V$ to its double dual. The map $\phi_V$ depends naturally on $V$, and its scalar multiples are the only natural transformations form the identity functor on the category of vector spaces to the double dual functor.

The map $\phi_V$ is injective for all $V$, and surjective exactly for those $V$ that are finite dimensional. This implies that my question is only interesting for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

> Can one characterize the image of $\phi_V:V\to V^{**}$?

The image is certainly not an arbitrary subspace (whatever that might mean…) For example, the image is a closed subspace for all Banach norms on $V^{**}$ that come from a Banach norm in $V$.

Comment: Keep in mind that if $V$ has a topology, then you need to specify whether you're interested in the algebraic dual space or the topological dual (which consists only of *continuous* functionals). I am not sure that there is a sensible notion of inherited topology from $V$ on the *algebraic* double dual $V^{**}$, which would be needed to state that $\phi_V$ forms a closed subspace

Comment: What do you mean by characterize? The Kaplanski-Erdős theorem gives $\dim{V^*}=|V|^*=|K|^{\dim V}$ where $K$ is the base field. The undecideability of the generalized continuum hypothesis implies that when $|K|=2$ (and perhaps in general, I'm not a set theorist), not even the dimension of the image of $V$ in $V^**$ can be recovered. In the topological setting, preduals of Banach spaces are in general not unique.

Comment: My best guess is that you want to characterize subspaces $W$ of $V^{**}$ for which the $K$-bilinear $V^*\otimes W\to V^*\otimes V^{**}\to K$ induces an isomorphism $V^*\cong W^*$... but that's probably difficult since even the dimension of $W$ is undecidable in ZFC (for $|K|=2$).